# Reload AJAX from an inline link already within an AJAX page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

http://fh80.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/fyp/ Live example

If you see this page, click sports/venues/athletes etc it lets you browse around but it is all called in via AJAX.

This works fine but I'm having problems with inline links. For example:

Go to sports

Go to athletics

Go to "Hampden Park" link in red

This link doesn't reload within the AJAX window, it loads it in a new window...

This is the code that should set anything with the class `ajaxLink` as possible to load the AJAX page into the div `#grid` (same as the way it's done for all the other pages)

```
var newLink = $('.ajaxLink');
            newLink.click(function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: newLink.attr('href'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#grid').remove();
                        successHandler(data)
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

Here is the code for the AJAX I am using (it's long):

```
//on document ready
$(function () {

    var ajaxElement = $('#browserMenu a, .ajaxLink');
    ajaxElement.on('click', function (e) {
        var src = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(src);
        //this element clicked
        var thisEl = $(this);
        var runAJAX = (src && src != '#') ? true : false;
        if (runAJAX) {
            var targetElement = $('#grid');
            var parentElement = $('#ajaxParent');
            if (src === 'index.html') {
                $('#content').load('index.html #inner-content', function () {
                    $('.selected-menu').each(function () {
                        $(this).removeClass('selected-menu');
                    });
                    thisEl.addClass('selected-menu');
                    $('#jsCode code pre').load('js/nocomments.js');
                });
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: src,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    statusCode: {
                        404: function () {

                            console.log(src + ' - not found');
                        }
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: successHandler
                });
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        }

        function successHandler(data) {
            targetElement.remove();
            //remove any selected classed
            $('.selected-menu').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('selected-menu');
            });
            thisEl.addClass('selected-menu');
            var newContent = $('<div id="grid" />');
            newContent
                .html(data) //grab the HTML from AJAX and place it in to <div id="content"> </div>                  
            .css("opacity", "0"); //hide the div until were ready to animate it in.
            parentElement.append(newContent);
            newContent.animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500);
            var newLink = $('.ajaxLink');
            newLink.click(function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: newLink.attr('href'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#grid').remove();
                        successHandler(data)
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }

    });

    $('#jsCode code pre').load('js/nocomments.js');
});
```

Comment: If you do not see why not, "cheat" :). try a trick:
You can try to add with jQuery a new div "grid2" after the div "grid", hide the "grid" and load the new "grid2".
it does not explain why it does not work, but it maybe help you. :)

Comment: Doesn't any provided answers solve your issue??? You didn't seem to have tried any, i mean at least, tried as you should, meaning delegating event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Why your code doesn't work

Let's step through what happens from when the user loads the page to when the user clicks on the "Hampden Park" link:

1. User loads the page:

   The document `ready` event handler is called. It adds a `click` event handler to `$('#browserMenu a, .ajaxLink')`, which matches the "Sports" link inside `<div id="browserMenu">`. There are no elements with the "ajaxLink" class in the document at this point, so only the four menu links get this `click` event handler.
2. User clicks on the "Sports" menu link:

   The `click` event handler from 1. is called. It loads content from the Sports page using Ajax, then passes that data to `successHandler()`. `successHandler()` removes the old `<div id="grid">` and adds a new `<div id="grid">` with the new content, which is a jQuery UI Tabs widget and content for the first tab (content for the other tabs are loaded using Ajax).

   At this point, `successHandler()` tries to add a `click` event handler to `$('.ajaxLink')`, but there are still **no elements with the "ajaxLink" class in the document**, so no `click` handlers are added.
3. User clicks on the "Athletics" tab:

   The jQuery UI Tabs widget loads the content for the Athletics page with Ajax and displays it.
4. User clicks on the "Hampden Park" link:

   This link has the "ajaxLink" class, but as noted in 2., it has no `click` event handler, so the browser opens this link normally.

---

### A better approach

For cases where content is loaded dynamically, it is easier to use [**event delegation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/311572) rather than trying to bind new event handlers every time the content changes.

Basically, every* event "bubbles up" from the original element where the event occurred, to its parent element, its parent's parent, all the way up to the `document` element. You can attach handlers to a parent element to respond to events that originate from its children.

From [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you will notice that `on()` takes an optional `selector` parameter. For example, with this:

```
$('body').on('click', handler);
```

`handler()` will be called whenever the user clicks on the page, no matter if the user clicked on a link, an image or a blank space. When a selector is present:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', handler);
```

`handler()` will only be called when the user clicks on a link (inside the `body` element). Any `click` events from elements that do not match the selector will be ignored (including any clicks that occur directly on the `body` element).

*As with many other cases, jQuery works around any browser inconsistencies so that event delegation works for all events.

---

### In your case

Assuming you want one event handler to handle clicks to both menu links and content links, you can attach a `click` event handler to either `<div class="slideWrapper">` or `<body>`, as they are parents / ancestors of both `<div id="browserMenu">` and `<div id="grid">`:

```
$('body').on('click', '#browserMenu a, .ajaxLink', function (e) {
    // load content using Ajax
    // on success, replace old content with new
});
```

Comment: Hey there. Your answer makes a lot of sense to me, but I do not get, why the successHandler does not get the `.ajaxLink` links from the newly loaded html as those are now in the DOM tree, arent they?

Comment: @func0der Are you referring to step 3? When the user clicks on the "Athletics" tab, the corresponding HTML is loaded by jQuery UI's code. `successHandler()` isn't called in this case.

Comment: No, I am referring to step 2 where `successHandler()` tries to find links with `.ajaxLink` and can not find any, though there are already added to the dom a line before.

Comment: @func0der The HTML loaded in step 2 doesn't contain any links with the "ajaxLink" class. You can load that page directly and view its source.

Comment: It does: http://fh80.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/fyp/pages/sports/athletics.html
That's why I am confused by your statement.

Comment: @func0der When you click "Sports" it loads http://fh80.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/fyp/pages/sports.html. When you click "Athletics", that's when it loads http://fh80.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/fyp/pages/sports/athletics.html.

Comment: Yeah, so the "Sports" page has no `.ajaxLink`, but all its sub tabs like "athlectics" are working. The "athletics" page has a `.ajaxLink` link, but is not working.

Comment: @func0der The "Athletics" tab is loaded by the jQuery UI Tabs widget (as explained in step 3). As I also mentioned, it doesn't call `successHandler()`. I suggest you try stepping through the code as I have shown.

Comment: Ah...sorry. I must have skipped the second paragraph of step 3.
Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `on` function of jQuery to do this. [Start here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). `click` will not work with dynamic content, but the newish event API will catch dynamic content generated from an AJAX response and inserted into the DOM. This is a google example from that page:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

What that does is catches all incoming `tr` elements into `dataTable`'s `tbody` and give them a `click` event.

Comment: Hmm I tried changing it to this but it doesn't work! newLink.on("click", function (e) {

Comment: @Francesca newLink.on("click", function (e) { .. } this is not what the answer provided you with. You need to delegate the event. Try it on the document $(document).on('click', '.AJAX_LINK_CLASS', function(){ ... })

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you need to attach the function to an element which is not loaded by ajax.

```
$('#grid').on('click', '.ajaxlink', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Since `#grid` is not modified by the ajax call, the event handler will stay in place.

Answer (score 0):

In response to my comment and since there was no validation , I propose another way to recover your data avoiding ajax calls that can be resource intensive .

The principle is to call once the static data and concerver .

For example, you have your `grid` div .

The first time you click on "Sports", verify that there is no div `grid-sport`, you create a div `grid-sport` in the `grid` with a div class `grid-class` , you made ​​the call to ajax to fill the `grid-sports` div.

Clicking "Athletics" , you hide the class `grid-class`, verify that there is no div `grid-athletics`, you create a div `grid-athletics` with `grid-class` (after the `grid-sports` div in the `grid` div), and you made ​​the call to ajax to fill the `grid-athletics`.

And so on for all the links ...

If you click again on "Athletics" for example, you hide the div that the `grid-class` class and there, verify that there is div `grid-athletics`, if your content is static (for the user session), show you the tag `grid-athletics`, otherwise, if the content should be dynamic you delete its contents and remade an ajax call.

With this method, you call once your static content.

I hope I have understood (translated by Google:))